# Get conjugations of French verbs using a HTML parser

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a program in python to automatically get conjugations of French verbs.
I do not want to hard-code any conjugations, and I could not find an API, so I decided to write a program that would send a request to the [Reverso French Conjugator](https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-french.html).

I find my code, however, to be untidy and hard-to-follow. I also feel as if there are not enough comments, yet I do not know how or where I should place them.

```
# Get packages
from html.parser import HTMLParser 
import requests

compacted = False # Whether or not to return a compacted output

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser): # Define a new html parser
    def __init__(self, verb, tense):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self) # Initialize (found on internet, not sure if there's a better way)

        # Initialize open/close boolean variables (don't know if there's a better way of this
        self.div_open = False 
        self.pronoun_open = False
        self.conjugation_open = False

        # Initialize tense
        self.tense = tense

        # Intialize tag list with verb
        self.tag_list = [["verb", verb]]
    
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        for attr in attrs: # Loop through attributes
            if self.div_open: 
                if attr[1] == "graytxt": # Pronouns
                    self.pronoun_open = True
                elif attr[1] == "verbtxt": # Conjugated verbs
                    self.conjugation_open = True
            elif attr[1] == self.tense: # Run only if the div matches with current tense
                self.div_open = True 
        
    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.pronoun_open: # If pronoun is open ...
            self.tag_list.append(["pronoun", data]) # ... add to tag list
        elif self.conjugation_open: # Same with conjugated verb
            self.tag_list.append(["conjugation", data])

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == "div": # Close div
            self.div_open = False
        elif tag == "i": # 2-in-1
            self.pronoun_open = False
            self.conjugation_open = False

    def get_tag_list(self):
        return self.tag_list # return the tag list

def parse_conjugations(compacted, tag_list):
    output = "" # Initialize output variable
    if compacted: 
        for tag in tag_list: # Loop through each tag
            if tag[0] == "verb":
                output += tag[1] + ":" # Append to output
            elif tag[0] == "conjugation":
                output += tag[1] + "."
    else:
        for tag in tag_list: # Same as before
            if tag[0] == "verb": 
                output += "Verb: " + tag[1] + "\n"
            elif tag[0] == "pronoun":
                output += tag[1]
            elif tag[0] == "conjugation":
                output += tag[1] + "\n"           
    return output

url = "https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-french-verb-{}-v1.html" # Url for French verbs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    verb = input("Input a french verb: ") # Get user input
    tense = input("Input the tense of this verb: ")

    request = requests.get(url.format(verb)) # Get data
    parser = MyHTMLParser(verb, tense) # Initialize parser
    parser.feed(request.text) # Feed parser
    print(parse_conjugations(compacted, parser.get_tag_list()), end="") # Print parsed data
```

Examples for tense input include (case sensitive):

- Indicatif Présent
- Indicatif Passé composé
- Indicatif Imparfait

Examples for verbs include:

- Avoir
- Être
- Falloir

The intended output (with tense "Indicatif Présent" and verb "avoir) should look like:

```
Verb: avoir
j'ai
tu as
il/elle a
nous avons
vous avez
ils/elles ont
```

Comment: Does this program work? I don't speak French, but I found a few verbs on the internet and tried them, along with various values for tense (but perhaps I did something wrong). In every case, the output was never more than this example: `Verb: parler`. Can you supply an example or two of verb-tense inputs that produce non-trivial outputs?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't clarify: examples for tenses are "Indicatif Présent", "Indicatif Passé composé", and "Indicatif Imparfait". I've tried them with verbs such as "avoir", "être", and "falloir" and I've gotten better results.

I'll add an edit clarifying the expected input and output.

Answer (score 3):

First of all well done - it works! I went through and made a few edits to your codes, making notes as I went through. I hope this is useful.

---

### Comments and style

1. I don't think you need the comment `# Get packages` above your import statements. These statements will appear in every Python module you ever write, so save yourself the trouble. You can assume the person reading your code has a fundamental grasp of the language.
2. In general, I think you have a good amount of comments. Focus on making the code clear rather than adding more and more comments - you don't want to end up with more comments than code.
3. The PEP8 Style Guide for Python (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends keeping each line to a maximum of 80 characters, so I recommend keeping your comments on separate lines except in some rare cases so that the code is more 'tall' than 'fat'.
4. For descriptions of what a function does, it is best practice to use docstrings in triple quotes (`"""`) rather than comments.
5. Avoid unnecessary comments that just say exactly the same thing as the code. `# return the tag list` before the line `return self.tag_list` in the function `get_tag_list` is a perfect example of this.
6. You wrote `# Append to output` for `verb` tags but not for `conjugation`. If being consistent feels repetitive, it's probably a good sign that you don't need the comment at all.
7. I added some extra comments after `if compacted:` and `else` as this is a good example of a place in your code where some explanation would help.
8. It is not clear to me what you mean by `# 2-in-1` so you may what to consider being more explicit, if there is any need for a comment here at all.

### Code structure

1. You have defined `compacted` as a global variable, presumably thinking that you will add functionality for the user to choose between compacted and non-compacted output at some point in the future. However you will not want to have this as a global variable ever, so it's better to just refer to it by name in the function call to make it clear what value you have chosen.
2. `URL` can go at the top of the module as a global constant (for which the convention is to use UPPERCASE names).
3. In general the code appears to be well-structured. I do not have an in-depth knowledge of `HTMLParser` so I can't comment on whether it is being used correctly, but reading through your code I was able to get a general understanding of how it works.

### Program design

1. It seems very user un-friendly to expect the user to name the tense they want, without any indication of what the possible input values are. Will it still work if I write 'indicatif présent' all in lowercase, or 'Indicatif Present' without the accent? It depends what your use case is, but if you are planning to show this program to other people the first improvement to make would probably be to present a list of options to the user. Something like:

> You can display the following tenses:
>
> IP: Indicatif Présent; IPC: Indicatif Passé composé; II: Indicatif Imparfait;
>
> Which tense would you like to display?

2. You'll also need to be able to handle invalid input, etc. to make the program intuitive to use.

---

Here's my edited version of your code. Please compare with your original code and take away any practices you think will help you.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser 
import requests

# URL for French verbs
URL = "https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-french-verb-{}-v1.html"


# ====================
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser): 
    """Define a new html parser"""

    def __init__(self, verb, tense):
        """Initialize"""

        # (There may be a better way to do this)
        HTMLParser.__init__(self) 

        # Initialize open/close boolean variables
        # (There may be a better way to do this)
        self.div_open = False 
        self.pronoun_open = False
        self.conjugation_open = False
        # Initialize tense
        self.tense = tense

        # Intialize tag list with verb
        self.tag_list = [["verb", verb]]
        
    
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        """Loop through attributes"""

        for attr in attrs:
            if self.div_open: 
                if attr[1] == "graytxt": 
                    # Pronouns
                    self.pronoun_open = True
                elif attr[1] == "verbtxt": 
                    # Conjugated verbs
                    self.conjugation_open = True
            # Run only if the div matches with current tense
            elif attr[1] == self.tense: 
                self.div_open = True 
        

    def handle_data(self, data):

        # If pronoun is open
        if self.pronoun_open: 
            # Add to tag list
            self.tag_list.append(["pronoun", data]) 
        # Same with conjugated verb
        elif self.conjugation_open:
            self.tag_list.append(["conjugation", data])


    def handle_endtag(self, tag):

        if tag == "div":
            # Close div
            self.div_open = False
        elif tag == "i":
            # 2-in-1  <== What do you mean?
            self.pronoun_open = False
            self.conjugation_open = False


    def get_tag_list(self):

        return self.tag_list 


# ====================
def parse_conjugations(tag_list, compacted):

    # Initialize output variable
    output = ""

    if compacted: 
        # Return on a single line without pronouns
        for tag in tag_list: 
            if tag[0] == "verb":
                output += tag[1] + ":"
            elif tag[0] == "conjugation":
                output += tag[1] + "."
    else:
        # Return on multiple lines with pronouns
        for tag in tag_list:
            if tag[0] == "verb": 
                output += "Verb: " + tag[1] + "\n"
            elif tag[0] == "pronoun":
                output += tag[1]
            elif tag[0] == "conjugation":
                output += tag[1] + "\n"     

    return output


# ====================
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Get user input
    verb = input("Input a french verb: ")
    tense = input("Input the tense of this verb: ")

    # Get data
    request = requests.get(URL.format(verb))
    # Initialize parser
    parser = MyHTMLParser(verb, tense) 
    # Feed parser
    parser.feed(request.text) 
    # Print parsed data
    print(
        parse_conjugations(parser.get_tag_list(), compacted=False),
        end=""
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

**Comments should not repeat what is already obvious from
the code**. Here are several offenders from your current comments:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser): # Define a new html parser

# Initialize tense
self.tense = tense

# Initialize tag list with verb
self.tag_list = [["verb", verb]]

for attr in attrs: # Loop through attributes

elif attr[1] == self.tense: # Run only if the div matches with current tense

if self.pronoun_open: # If pronoun is open ...
    self.tag_list.append(["pronoun", data]) # ... add to tag list

for tag in tag_list: # Loop through each tag
    if tag[0] == "verb":
        output += tag[1] + ":" # Append to output
```

**Comments should address substantive issues**. Sounds good, but what is
"substantive"? One example is what does the program, class, function, or method
do, or what is its purpose? For example, a simple script might have a comment
(or docstring) at the top with an example input and corresponding output.
Without requiring any reading any code at all, that communicates the intention
of the program. A related comment might show the contrast between full output
and "compacted" output (by contrast, your current comment for the `compacted`
variable only hints on the distinction, without providing very much useful
information). Another example of a substantive comment would be to provide a
small mockup of the expected HTML structure. Nearly all of your program's
complexity deals with parsing HTML, but nowhere do you tell the reader in
explicit terms what form the document takes. By running your script, printing
the whole HTML file, and doing some searching in Vim, I was able to
reverse-engineer things to figure out that all of the relevant data was coming
from one `<div>`. Your script could include a comment illustrating that
structure in very clear terms (as shown below). Other substantive comments
might help the reader understand less-obvious aspects of the algorithm (if
any), clarify the organization of key data structures used in the program (if
any), point out unexpected issues or gotchas discovered while writing the code,
list any preconditions or assumptions around which the code was written, and so
forth. Basically, comments should be explaining anything important that is not
already obvious from the code. They can also be used as an organizational
device -- sort of like headings at the top of each section/paragraph of code --
to assist a reader trying to quickly scan or read the code.

```
# This function parses HTML having a <div> like the following:
#
# <div class="blue-box-wrap" mobile-title="Indicatif Pr&#xE9;sent">
#   ...
#   <ul class="wrap-verbs-listing">
#     <li>
#       <i class="graytxt">je </i>
#       <i class="verbtxt">mange</i>
#     </li>
#     ... etc for the other pronouns
#   </ul>
# </div>
```

**Put comments on their own lines in almost all cases**. Because we are writing
substantive comments, some of them might need to span multiple lines. In more
complex situations, they might even require a fair bit of discussion to explain
what's going on. Line-trailing comments cannot scale up to that level of
information. In rare circumstances, line-trailing comments might be effective,
if they are very short and if the comments are taking advantage of vertical
alignment to compare/contrast adjacent lines of code in the program (eg, a set
of related variables or operations). Even in those cases, however, putting
comments on their own lines is often more effective and easier to edit if the
program evolves over time.

**Select a more convenient HTML parser**. The HTMLParser in the standard library
is very awkward to use: I've done it a few times, it was always a pain in the
ass, and I quickly forgot most of the details. But the Python ecosystem offers
[many
alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709079/parsing-html-using-python).
As an illustration, I tried BeautifulSoup, which I've never used before. After
downloading the HTML for the verb *manger* and reading a couple of examples
from the documentation, I was able to figure out how to parse the data using
the code below. A real expert on this topic -- or even someone like yourself
who committed to reading a full tutorial on BeautifulSoup -- could probably
come up with something even more convenient and robust.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main():
    tense = 'Indicatif Imparfait'
    with open('manger.html') as fh:
        text = fh.read()
    for pronoun, verb in parse_conjugations(text, tense):
        print(pronoun, verb)

def parse_conjugations(text, tense):
    # Take HTML text and verb tense.
    # Yields (PRONOUN, VERB) tuples.
    queries = {
        'tense': {'mobile-title': tense},
        'pronoun': {'class': 'graytxt'},
        'verb': {'class': 'verbtxt'},
    }
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
    for li in soup.find('div', attrs = queries['tense']).find_all('li'):
        yield (
            li.find('i', attrs = queries['pronoun']).text.strip(),
            li.find('i', attrs = queries['verb']).text.strip(),
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

This question already has a couple of good answers, but let me add my 2 cents:

1. **Comments and code-documentation**: Comments should add some meaningful insights about the code instead of restating what is already apparent from the line of code itself. Also, there's a distinction to be made between comments and triple-quoted [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring) placed at the start of a code-entity; the latter are used by the built-in `help(obj)` command and documentation-generators such as Sphinx. In your case, you should add a docstring at the very top of your script summarizing what the program does, as well as docstrings for at least the top-level entities such as your class and the `parse_conjugations` function. Also, try to place lengthier comments on their own line so that they don't break the 80-characters per line max-limit.
2. **Linting and whitespace issues**: There is a class of utility programs called linters that auto-check your code for stylistic errors amongst other things. You can use the [pylint module](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/) for example: `python -m pylint your_script.py`. This revealed several lines with trailing whitespace in your code, for instance.
3. **Input validation with argparse**: If you're accepting command-line arguments from the user, you should consider using the [`argparse` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) which automates input validation and error messaging as well as help messaging for your program. You can easily restrict the 'tense' argument to a fixed set of choices, for instance.
4. **BeautifulSoup**: As [suggested by FMc](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/272487/254751), use the bs4 package's BeautifulSoup for parsing HTML instead of `HTMLParser` as it allows you to select elements much more easily using attribute-filters.